# How can I add an element to a json object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```js
var obj={"student":[{"id":1,"name":"mark"}]}
```

For example I have this object I want to add another element to it such as this:

```
var teacher=  "teacher":[{"id":1,"name":"Stacy"}]
```

to make this new object:

```
var objnew= {"student":[{"id":1,"name":"mark"}], "teacher":[{"id":1,"name":"Stacy"}] }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
var objnew = Object.assign({}, obj, teacher);
```

Comment: You should maybe add some code to explain what you mean, or link to some [online documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). At the moment this answer is rather sparse.